# How to get pointer to IUnknown in C#

Tags: c#, com, interop, directshow

.NET interop wraps COM objects into .NET objects (runtime-callable wrappers, RCWs), which hide the usual interface querying. In order to register a COM object representing a filter graph with the Running Objects Table, I need the (native) address of its IUnknown interface (see [How can I reverse engineer a DirectShow graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832/how-can-i-reverse-engineer-a-directshow-graph)).

So the question is: How can I get a COM object's IUnknown pointer in C#?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getiunknownforobject.aspx).