# How to declare same interface in separate library

Tags: c#, interface, com, directshow

I need to have the same interface declared in multiple assemblies - but not reference a common library.

I have identical definitions of the interface, but am getting this error when I try to create an instance of it from another application:

> Unable to cast object of type 'myFilter' to type
>   'DirectShow.IBaseFilter'

(myFilter is declared like: `public class myfilter : DirectSow.IBaseFilter...`)

The source object is registered using RegAsm.exe

Both assemblies have the declaration:

```
[ComImport, System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity,
Guid("56a86895-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IBaseFilter : IMediaFilter
...
```

The code is copied, so the `IMediaFilter` and all other declarations are exactly the same.

I try to create an instance of the object using this:

```
 Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("A3927399-E3AE-41E2-B094-0EA815CC9B9C"));
 IBaseFilter filter = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

How can I cast an object across assemblies?

Comment: *Why* don't you want to reference a common assembly?

Comment: Why aren't you pulling the interface into its own assembly and having them all reference that?

Comment: "I need to have the same interface declared in multiple assemblies - but not reference a common library". That isn't possible. Unless they all reference one definition, then the interfaces aren't the same. C# doesn't support duck typing.

Comment: Hard to guess why programmers insist on shooting their leg off like this.  It is technically possible, COM interfaces support type equivalence solely by their [Guid] since .NET 4.0.  A feature that's use to implement the "Embed interop types" property of an interop assembly.  Google ".net type equivalence" to learn more.

Comment: this is for a DirectShow project that uses COM. I can't share common code with other vendors, yet the objects I make successfully load in graphedit and are available to all the other video processing systems on my machine.

Comment: Related: [Converting between 2 different libraries using the same COM interface in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758316/converting-between-2-different-libraries-using-the-same-com-interface-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 2):

By definition: you can't. Two separate interfaces what are nothing to do with each other never will be "is a" relationship with each other even they have "same" named and identical members.

The professional solution is separate the interfaces in a standalone assembly, then reference this assembly as many other assemblies as you want. All other is considered hacking (in C#/.NET).

To apply the described solution in this particular case you'll need 2 or 3 assemblies:

Assembly #1: (which "defines" the interface). This "defining" is a COM interface import this particular case:

```
 [ComImport, System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity,
 Guid("56a86895-0ad4-11ce-b03a-0020af0ba770"),
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
 public interface IBaseFilter : IMediaFilter
```

Assembly #2:
    Refers to Assembly #1, and contains a class which implements the interface

Assembly #3: 
    Refers to Assembly #1 and #2, and can access and use/cast the class in Assembly #2. Do not (re)import the interface here. That would be an identical but completely "other" interface for .NET even it has the very same member signatures.

I think the Assembly #1 and #2 could merged in one. Make sure both the interface declaration and class definition are both public. The key is not import twice the COM interface instead import once and refer to it.

**Edit: Reflecting to the comment:**

Do not confuse COM interfaces and classes with .NET interfaces. (btw the comment mentions a class id not an interface id, which are two different things in COM.)

Accessing COM classes and interfaces in .NET are highly supported via an interop layer. The interop layer does all conversions and marshalling for you, and you access the COM component via a convenient  .NET interface. However this interface are defined in an (interop) assambly, and those assemblies (for well known, and often used COM components) are distributed, or part of the download of the original COM stuff. So literally they are on *every* machine where they needed.

Also a concept difference, that in COM the client (referring component) refers to the server (referenced component) by *only* a guid (this is the class id), then asks a polymorphic implementation of an interface by also with *only* a guid. So the client can use a component's particular interface by knowing only two guids, and executing 1-2 COM OS call. This is black boxed for you in the interop layer. In .NET the binding between the client and the server are much stronger.

If *you* would like to define such kind of interface then you must do the same: somehow define the interface in *one* assembly then distribute it with every machine where other assemblies are using the interface and referencing this interface.

Options in case you do not accept the best practice:

- You could use reflection to achieve similar looser binding, but in this case that's considered hacking and seems to be unnecessary. Be prepared that your method names and class names will be strings, or at least not typing them correctly will not cause compile error, but will cause runtime errors.
- You can also define and implement COM components in .NET, but I don't think this is the goal. COM is a legacy (and cool) technology what was *very* progressive (and not understood/criticized) in its time, but this was more than a quarter century ago (when it was introduced)

Comment: If I use class id "70E102B0-5556-11CE-97C0-00AA0055595A", I get a video renderer that is built in somewhere, yet it somehow successfully exposes the IBaseFilter interface.

Comment: Being that this particular case is DirectShow, my program is accessing system level known interfaces - so the common global level interface is buried in the OS. A class in my library implements that interface, but for some reason, I can't access it from a separate assembly. Both of my assemblies can access everything else on the system that implements that interface, and everything on the system can access my classes - it's just that my 2 classes can't access each other.

Comment: @g.pickardou, actually, you can, but it's a [hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26796534/1768303).

Comment: Please review my edit, which describes how to apply the original principle in this COM particular case.

Answer (score 0):

(This is the solution of the question author [DanW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415586/danw))

In the DLL:
Make assembly `COM-Visible = checked`

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComExport
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("EAA4976A-45C3-4BC5-BC0B-E474F4C3C83F")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [TypeIdentifier()]
    public interface ComClass1Interface
    {
        string DoCall();
    }

    [Guid("0D53A3E8-E51A-49C7-944E-E72A2064F938")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class ComClass1 : ComClass1Interface
    {
        public string DoCall()
        {
            return "internal function called";
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "comclass1.tostring";
        }
    }
}
```

then in the EXE

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComExportTester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Load += (o1, e) => Close();

            Type t;
            object o;
            ComExport.ComClass1Interface i1;
            string s = "";
            try
            {
                t = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("0D53A3E8-E51A-49C7-944E-E72A2064F938"));
                s += "Type found \t: " + (t == null ? "no" : "yes") + "\n";
                o = t == null ? null : Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                s += "object created \t: " + (o == null ? "no" : o.ToString()) + "\n";
                i1 = o as ComExport.ComClass1Interface;
                s += "interface cast \t: " + (i1 == null ? "no" : "yes") + "\n";
                if (i1 != null)
                    s += i1.DoCall() + "\n";
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                s += x.Message + "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
    }
}
namespace ComExport
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("EAA4976A-45C3-4BC5-BC0B-E474F4C3C83F")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [TypeIdentifier()]
    public interface ComClass1Interface
    {
        string DoCall();
    }
}
```

in both:

set x86 or x64 (compiling and running in "Any CPU" mode throws a "not registered" exception!)