# Get skype video stream

Tags: windows, video-capture, skype

My task is to get and record skype video / audio stream. As I see from Skype API reference there is no direct way to do so, some people suggest me to capture directX stream of skype application itself. But I'm a bit stuck here.

Could you please give some advice / links / solutions on how to get skype video stream (it's more important than audio one) into my desktop application.

I'll be happy to give any other info on this.

Thank you!

Comment: For accessing filter graph in Skype this could be helpful [How can I reverse engineer a DirectShow graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832/how-can-i-reverse-engineer-a-directshow-graph)

Comment: @DmitryShkuropatsky: Skype doesn't use DirectShow

Comment: could you just record screen just like screen recorders like Camtasia do?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Any idea how evaer does it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you want to using some plugin or to make app for call record...If you need plugin you can use http://shop.skype.com/apps/Call-recording-audio-video/Pamela-Call-Recorder.html . If you need to make app, then u can use API for stream and just pipe it some file.