# Is there any helper tool for creating graphedit files "on the fly" (programmatically)

Tags: windows, directshow, graphedit, avisynth

I notice that avisynth can accept as input a "live directshow source" only through a graphedit file that includes that source in it.  Is there any help tool out there to create a graphedit file on the fly, given you know a capture sources name (and/or the output format you want from that pin)?

ref: http://betterlogic.com/roger/2012/05/avisynth-live-capture

The graphedit file syntax is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388788(v=vs.85).aspx (though it doesn't mention how to discover the right values to put in there).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050074/how-to-change-directshow-filter-properties-c/27931102#27931102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file format is in the neighboring section on MSDN: [Saving a Filter Graph to a GraphEdit File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . Having a filter graph AND filter there with support for persistence (`IPeristStream` interface and friends), the function `SaveGraphFile` on MSDN article will save graph into GraphEdit-loadable file.