# Direct Show Error - Pins cannot connect due to not supporting the same transport. (0x80040266)

Tags: video, directshow, directshow.net

This error happens intermittently when attempting to play a video file using DirectShow.net, with an embedded player in an application.

The video file will play correctly several times in a session of the application, then fail when the graph builder cannot connect filters.

The video file(s) are AVI format using a JPEG video stream (MJPG Codec) They were encoded using ADOBE Premier Pro.

What tools or trace settings are available to debug this sort of problem?  Where is the best strategy for getting a diagnostic?

Comment: Have you DirectShow application sources or is third-part?
If so you can try to enable remote connection to graphedit in order to see graph state.
Sound like some issue on correctly release directshow filters or graph between sessions.

Comment: The problem does happen after a previously successful session closes and the application tries to start another session with a new file. It only happens when the new video file size exceeds 2GB.  I do have the application sources.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen transport errors often in DirectShow but when I have they're usually associated with video renderer issues in my experience.

Pay attention to any graph events that are occuring.

You might find the [GDCL monitor filter](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/downloads.htm) usually for tracing what's going on between filters when problems are hard to trace. Can be extended to log information of interest easily enough.

Find interfaces that you can use to interrogate the status of your renderer filter(s) before and after the errors.

Some useful techniques mentioned in answers to this question, particularly exporting graph to ROT and connecting with a graph editor.
[How can I reverse engineer a DirectShow graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832/how-can-i-reverse-engineer-a-directshow-graph)