# Spying on the filtergraph of an application that cannot be recompiled

Tags: c++, windows, filter, graph, directshow

If an application such as TV tuner doesn't add its filtergraph to Running Objects Table and therefore GRAPHEDT.EXE cannot spy on the application's graph, are there any other ways to see the application's filtergraph, short of recompiling the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you regiter [DirectShow Spy](https://alax.info/blog/777) in your system, it starts publishing filter graphs automatically, so that you can use GraphEdit or [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) to connect to remote filter graphs of applications that did not publish graphs in first place.

A few notes:

1. you need to COM register the DLL that matches bitness of target application (or register both)
2. you need to have additionally COM registered proppage.dll from Windows 10 SDK ([more on this](https://alax.info/blog/1430))
3. GraphEdit needs to be executed at the same privilege elevation level as the target application

See also: [How can I reverse engineer a DirectShow graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070337/868014)

Comment: It seems that all blogs (alax.info/blog/1430, alax.info/blog/1385) point to various versions of the DLL (1.0.0.807, 1.0.0.647) that are actually the same (alax.info/svn/public/trunk/DirectShowSpy/_Bin/Win32/Release Trace/DirectShowSpy.dll), and that link is dead. Would it be possible to update the links, so they would point to those earlier versions of the DLL? The latest DLL doesn't register on my system ("function not found")--it requires a newer version of Windows than I have.

Comment: Oh... so unfortunate, eventually svn integration on the web hosting is dead. Here it is the temporary download link: https://alax.info/temp/2021-02-15/DirectShowSpy-20210215.zip

Comment: ^^^ these are the latest, what OS you need this for? Windows XP? I might need to rebuild this using legacy toolset.

Comment: I have some old builds from 2011-2013, place them there: https://alax.info/temp/2021-02-15/archive/ maybe something works out for you.

Comment: I found the DLLs at alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/DirectShowSpy. The application works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm trying to build DirectShow Spy, but I can't find roatltrace.h. I have a feeling that it should be in alax.info/trac/public/log/trunk/Common/alax.info, but it's not there.

Comment: These files were never public, and the source code have been reference and partial